# Firebase Snapshot working correctly to retrieve user info but not being able to retrieve Profile Picture - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uiimageview

I am getting a weird issue with my snapshot where the username and email are being fetched but my snapshot returns nil for a profile picture.

[image: Here's my firebase database structure]

```
func displayUserInformation() {

    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in


        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            self.username.text! = (dictionary["username"] as? String)!
            self.email.text! = (dictionary["email"] as? String)!

            let profileImageUrl =  (dictionary["photoUrl"] as? String)!
            let url = URL(string: profileImageUrl)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                        return
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.profilePicture.image? = UIImage(data: data!)!
                        print(data!)
                    }
                }).resume()


            print(profileImageUrl)
            print(snapshot)
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

The snapshot is working and the profileUrl DOES show the data so I don't know what might be the problem. Here's what the print(profileImageUrl) shows and the snapshot

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gastet-4cfd2.appspot.com/o/profileImages%2F031F0B9F-AA41-4C16-8446-CD07893F2CA7.jpg?alt=media&token=c0e07615-8166-40e7-8d92-22bb8fbc8c8e
Snap (wL40cuYrGAVNdCVvCGUhKsD64RH2) {
    email = "ximeft29@gmail.com";
    photoUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gastet-4cfd2.appspot.com/o/profileImages%2F031F0B9F-AA41-4C16-8446-CD07893F2CA7.jpg?alt=media&token=c0e07615-8166-40e7-8d92-22bb8fbc8c8e";
    username = ximeft29;
}
```

Comment: A first link it looks like `photoUrl` should work if the `email` and `username` work too. Can you print `profileImageUrl` and `snapshot` and edit your question to show both?

Comment: Hi Frank! It does print everything... I just edited the question to show what the prints show

Answer (score 1):

I've duplicated your example in a sample project and have successfully been able to get it to asynchronously fetch the picture from the URL.

I've also rewritten the function to handle unwrapping the data a bit more gracefully. Any questions feel free to ask!

```
func displayUserInformation() {

    if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {

        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUser.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject],
               let username = dictionary["username"] as? String,
               let email = dictionary["email"] as? String,
               let urlString = dictionary["photoUrl"] as? String,
               let url = URL(string: urlString) {

                self.username.text = username // Set the username
                self.email.text = email // Set the email

                /*
                 * Fetch the image asyncronously
                 */
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                    if let error = error {
                        print("There was an error fetching the image from the url: \n", error)
                    }

                    if let data = data, let profilePicture = UIImage(data: data) {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                            self.profilePicture.image = profilePicture // Set the profile picture
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("Something is wrong with the image data")
                    }

                }).resume()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Garret! Thanks for taking the time! I actually just used your code and now neither the profile nor the username appear. I don't know if maybe it has something to do with my xcode file or what might be the problem :/